# Can't Access Windows after Dual Boot Install - Wiped Windows Partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have read other posts and haven't found a solution after 10+ hours of torturous attempts! :(  I would be so grateful for any help or advice.

Here's what's happened:

- I installed Ubuntu 21.10 as a dual boot along with windows.  Both worked okay
- I decided I want the LTS version, so overwrote 21.10 with 20.04.  I got the warning messages that:
  *- The partition devices of the following devices are going to be changed SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)* (i'm wondering if I screwed up on this one???)
  *- The following partitions are going to be formatted: partition #6 of CSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4* (I think this should be fine, its the correct Ubuntu partition)

Since overwriting with LTS, I can't boot into Windows.  It displays 'Preparing Automatic Repair' but can't boot.

I have tried, to no benefit:

- Reinstalling Ubuntu.
- Making a windows boot USB to reinstall it, but I can't do it from USB, apparently (apparently Dell requires re-installation to commence from within windows).
- Some command prompt efforts - after 'Preparing Automatic Repair' I could access a windows prompt where I tried these: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/total-identified-windows-installations-0/52359f87-de4a-41dc-b0c3-cc275e1d9fbf  ...this didn't work as c:\boot could not be found (disk wiped???)

In Ubuntu, gparted shows the ‘used’ amount of disk as a dash (--), so I’m not sure if that means I’ve wiped that partition by mistake?

- Any way to check if I've wiped the windows partition? I could not see any of my files in the windows command prompt, above (couldn't view the drive)
- Any way to restore the partition, if I've accidentally wiped it?
- Any other suggestions or advice?  I have no idea how to get windows back onto my laptop, even if I accept my data is lost and do a clean install (given that windows boot USB doesn't seem to be enabled for reinstalling windows, unless I'm already logged in.

[gparted... showing data wiped on sda4? or is that normal for used data to be listed as a dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1gbt.png)

Comment: A few questions... how are you booting to Windows? GRUB? The computer's boot menu? If GRUB, try the computer's boot menu. Also, (on Ubuntu), open GParted, and take a screenshot of the partitions on your system drive, and [edit] your question to include that, please.

Comment: Lets see details. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: - I tried both going into windows from GRUB, and also prioritising windows in the bios so that it boots directly, and its the identical result. 
- Here is the bootinfo summary: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CQHwVjbs2D/  I ran the recommended repair a couple of times yesterday, and I think just now too (sorry, not sure how to get the report without running the recommended repair).
-  I will add a screenshot of gparted showing nothing used on the windows partition sda4 (not sure if that's just Ubuntu not reading ntfs, data having been wiped, or something else?)

Comment: Any ideas on how to check, from Ubuntu or during boot:
- if the ntfs windows portion files have been wiped?
- if they have been wiped, if there is any way to restore them (from Ubuntu or during boot)